# jQuery appendTo leaves white space in previous parent container

Tags: jquery, appendto, removing-whitespace

I'm using appendTo to move a couple of elements around in the DOM:

```
jQuery('.footer-pre-home.box.s5,.footer-two.box.s5').appendTo('.footer .copyright');
```

This works fine. However, when they are removed, they are leaving a single whitespace character in their previous parent node "pre-footer". This is preventing me from using the css :empty psuedo class on the pre-footer element.

Any way to fix this in the appendTo?

The original html is below:

```
<div class="pre-footer">
    <div class="footer-two box s5">
        <div class="textwidget">
            <ul class="social flat">
                <li class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com"></a></li>
                <li class="facebook"><a href="http://facebook.com"></a></li>
                <li class="google"><a href="http://plus.google.com"></a></li>
                <li class="youtube"><a href="http://youtube.com"></a></li>
                <li class="linkedin"><a href="http://linkedin.com"></a></li>
                <li class="rssfeed"><a href="feed/"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

After the appendTo, the computed pre-footer html looks like this:

```
<div class="pre-footer">
</div>
```

I can't remove the node because there may be elements inside it that are not targets of the appendTo. However, in this case, not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.appendTo` only accepts target, it doesn't leave `textNode`, there is `textNode` in your element, instead of using `:empty` selector you can use the `.filter()` method and check the length of the trimmed content:

```
var $empty = $(".footer .pre-footer").filter(function() {
  return !$.trim(this.innerHTML).length;      
  // return $.trim(this.innerHTML) === '';
});
```

Comment: I'm running this in console and its returning undefined. I'm using css to verify: .footer .pre-footer:empty{display:none!important}

Comment: @ScottB Well, I though you are using jQuery `:empty` selector, it doesn't remove the spaces, it filters the elements that have only whitespace or have no content. try `$(".pre-footer").filter(function() {
  return !$.trim(this.innerHTML).length;      
}).hide();`

Comment: +1 Yep, your answer works with the revised code and using jQuery empty vs CSS empty. Thanks! I was thinking that you were using jQuery trim to remove the empty node whitespace in order for CSS :empty to work.